# Truncate #inspect output in irb (ruby)

Tags: ruby, stdout, irb, inspect

I want to truncate #inspect output in irb (a large output must be cropped to MAX_LEN).

Currently, I override :inspect, :to_s methods for all specific objects.

Is there are other solution?

- change $stdout ?
- other?

Answer (score 5):

For a clean solution, `gem install hirb`. [hirb](http://github.com/cldwalker/hirb) pages irb's returned values if they get too long.

If you want to monkeypatch irb:

```
module IRB
  class Irb
    def output_value
     @context.last_value.to_s.slice(0, MAX_LEN)
    end
  end
end
```

I don't recommend this because it's a hack and breaks any time gems like ap and hirb are required.

Instead of monkeypatching irb, I'd recommend trying [ripl](http://github.com/cldwalker/ripl), an irb alternative that is meant to extended.
The above as a ripl plugin would be:

```
require 'ripl'
module Ripl::SlicedInspect
  def format_result(result)
    result_prompt + result.inspect.slice(MAX_LEN)
  end
end
Ripl::Shell.send :include, Ripl::SlicedInspect
```

With this plugin, you could require it as needed or add to your ~/.riplrc if you want to always use it.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is good.

It involves no dark magic, which might make the code less understandable and error-prone.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just in IRB - you could define a monkeypatch in irb itself and or load a file that monkeypatches inspect via 'load'. This way you keep it out of your core codebase but you still get the functionality you need w/o having to override inspect in every class you wish to inspect....

Answer (score 1):

If it's because you have a nested hash or something that's hard to decipher, try awesome_print. You can make it the default output formatter in irb by placing the following in your .irbrc:

```
require 'ap'

module IRB
  class Irb
    def output_value
      ap @context.last_value
    end
  end
end
```

This makes objects with lots of data easy to decipher in IRB.

Even if you don't use awesome_print, you can truncate output using this same technique so you don't have to override to_s in your code.

Answer (score 1):

For rails 3.1.1+, place the code below in helpers/irb_helper.rb

```
module IRB
  class Irb
    MAX_LEN = 10000

    def output_value
      if (@context.inspect_last_value.length > MAX_LEN)
        printf @context.return_format, "#{@context.inspect_last_value[0..MAX_LEN]} <- Truncated"
      else
        printf @context.return_format, @context.inspect_last_value
      end
    end
  end
end
```

If you'd like to customize your output more, check irb's source at https://github.com/Ruby/Ruby/blob/trunk/lib/irb.rb

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes modify the objects themselves (via a module called `BoringInspect` which I `include` into the relevant classes) so that exception messages are also manageable.

Comment: @banister: I didn't realize you knew me that well! Was that a +1 or a -1?

Comment: I read your pull request removing swear words from ruby-core..you're not the kind of guy i'd invite to a dinner party! *yawn* ;)

Comment: @banister: Ah, that! Anyway, was it meant to be an upvote or a downvote?