# Generic way to paginate output of IRB or Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination, irb, rails-console

The output of an IRB command is often too large for one "screen" 
(even if I scroll up - I am using Windows - I cannot get to the start of the output).

Is there a generic way to scroll/paginate through the output of IRB/Rails console. In Unix you use "| more" or "| less" to do so, but that doesn't work in IRB.

The workaround I am using now is to apply ranges on enumerables, example:

```
puts YAML::dump User.methods.sort[0..50]
puts YAML::dump User.methods.sort[50..100]
```

etc...

I've also seen [extra plugins to install or monkeypatching IRB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385064/truncate-inspect-output-in-irb-ruby), but I was wondering whether there was something natively built in...

Comment: You might check out the Console project for Windows. It's a different front-end to the windows command line that gives tabs, better scrollback, better text selection, etc. http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/

Comment: You can always just dump it to a file and open it in an editor if you like. Making a method that does that and cranks open `notepad.exe` isn't hard.

Comment: It used to work out of the box with ubuntu and zsh, however since ruby 3.0 its broken for me, anybody?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [hirb](http://tagaholic.me/hirb/), it's a small extension library for irb and it has [pagination](http://tagaholic.me/2009/06/19/page-irb-output-and-improve-ri-with-hirb.html) among other enchantments.

Comment: I was a bit sceptical of installing new libraries at first, but hirb works fine.  Also found out about https://github.com/janlelis/irbtools - which includes hirb.  Thx!